# AngularJS write on an image with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I have an image in my `html` that I get with an id:

```
<img id={{idImage}} ng-src="http://localhost:3000/images/{{idImage}}"/>
```

I have in one of my scope some coordinate (x, y, w, h).

In my controller:

```
$scope.coordinate;
```

But I don't know how to draw with canvas on the image according to the coordinates.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you use .svg ? have you tried anything so far ? Are you open to using other libs like d3 ?

Comment: I have a .html (because I have other info to display on the page). I would prefer using Canvas but don't know libs d3.

Comment: Have you tried to learn how to use canvas before posting this question? If you have: do you have a concrete question about how to draw in canvas? If you haven't: please delete the question and ask again after you have tried something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following simple example.

```
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById($scope.idImage);
var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');

$scrope.draw = function() {
context.drawImage($scope.idImage, $scope.coordinate.x, $scope.coordinate.y, $scope.coordinate.w, $scope.coordinate.h);
}
```

[Fiddle JS Example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/kneDX/)
[Fiddle JS Example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/)

There is nothing special about the draw in canvas just because you're using angular.

Some excellent examples here : [Draw HTML5 Canvas](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas)

Comment: The second JSFiddle example is not in Angular way.